# Rename the 'Blatantly off-topic' close reason

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, close-reasons

I noticed a community-specific close reason was created and called 'Blatantly off-topic.' However, for users without the close votes privilege, the 'Other' close reason is renamed to 'Blatantly off-topic.' I think it would look weird to <500 users to have 'Blatantly off-topic' listed twice. I think we should take the approach Stack Overflow and Ask Ubuntu and others took.

Stack Overflow:

> Not about programming or software development

Ask Ubuntu:

> Not about an official Ubuntu flavor

Current PLDI:

> <s>Blatantly off-topic</s>

Proposed PLDI:

> Not about programming language design or implementation

Or something similar.

Comment: For clarification for users who don't have close vote privilege the "Other" close reason where you'd supply free text is replaced with a *flag* for "Blatantly off-topic". So it's indeed redundant to have a "Blatantly off-topic" *close reason* as that's what "Other" serves as.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The close reason has been renamed to "Not about programmining language design or implementation", and has been given the description:

> This question is not about programming language design or implementation, within the scope defined in the help center. Do not use this close reason if the question would also be on-topic on another Stack Exchange site. Questions about the Programming Language Design and Implementation site itself should be migrated to Meta instead.

It has also been placed at the top of the order of close reason display. This means that the two flag options are not directly together.

On a post, the close notices will appear as:

[image]